# How to find if we are running unit test in Dart (Flutter)

Tags: android, unit-testing, flutter, dart

While calling a function from unit test in Flutter (Dart), how can I find if I am running unit test or real application?
I want to pass different data if it's in unit test.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if App is running in a Testing Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58407382/check-if-app-is-running-in-a-testing-environment)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can use the following to check if you're running a test.

```
Platform.environment.containsKey('FLUTTER_TEST')
```

**Solution for web below**

Note that the code above doesn't work on web as the `Platform` class is part of `dart:io` which is not available on web. An alternative solution that works for all platforms including web would be to use `--dart-define` build environment variable. It is available from Flutter 1.17

Example of running tests with `--dart-define`:

`flutter drive --dart-define=testing_mode=true --target=test_driver/main.dart`

In code you can check this environment variable with the following code:

`const bool.fromEnvironment('testing_mode', defaultValue: false)`

Not using const can lead to the variable not being read on mobile, see [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/55870#issuecomment-620776138).

Comment: `Platform` is defined in `dart:io`

Comment: I can't find an equivalent for Flutter web (since `dart:io` isn't available). Anyone know how to accomplish this in Flutter web?

Comment: @Noland you can write `if (kIsWeb == false && Platform.environment.containsKey('FLUTTER_TEST'))`  and cover `flutter web` .

Comment: This does not work for integration tests for me.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is right but if you want to check for a testing environment without breaking your web code, you can use the [universal_io](https://pub.dev/packages/universal_io) package.

```
Platform.environment.containsKey('FLUTTER_TEST')
```

On the web, Platform.environment will return an empty map instead of crashing your app.