# Flutter Web - How to check if the app is running in a test environment

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, flutter-test

In those questions:

- [How to find if we are running unit test in Dart (Flutter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59028609/how-to-find-if-we-are-running-unit-test-in-dart-flutter)
- [Check if App is running in a Testing Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58407382/check-if-app-is-running-in-a-testing-environment)

The given solution is to use

```dart
Platform.environment.containsKey('FLUTTER_TEST')
```

but `Platform` comes from `dart:io` which is not supported on web.
If I import it from [`universal_io`](https://pub.dev/packages/universal_io), it returns `false` when I run the tests with

```
flutter test --platform chrome
```

How to get a similar method/variable in a web environment?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to detect if you're in a test?

You could always just create a top-level static in a library you control

`bool runningInATest = false;` and then set it to true in your test app?

Comment: During the tests, some services might want to mock some side effects like reading files/creating them/writing in the cache etc.
Yes, I still could create this variable, but I would want it to be final, so devs cannot change it. This requires some work and if something is already done like `Platform.environment.containsKey('FLUTTER_TEST')`, it is better to not redo the work

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for a solution but the line:

```
Platform.environment.containsKey('FLUTTER_TEST')
```

or the line:

```
Get.testMode
```

do not seem to work during integration testing, for example. So I just created a singleton class that holds a variable isTest set to false as default.

```
class TestController {
  static final _testController = TestController._internal();

  TestController._internal();

  factory TestController() {
    return _testController;
  }

  bool isTest = false;
}
```

And i change it to true at the start of the integration test:

```
void main() {
  enableFlutterDriverExtension();
  TestController().isTest = true;
  app.main();
}
```

Maybe is not that elegant as a solution, I know, but it works in my case at least. That way I can successfully inject the appropriate dependencies I need for test and production environments.

```
 void _setWindowAndInjectDependencies() {
    final isTest = TestController().isTest;
    DesktopWindow.setWindowSize(const Size(1060, 960));
    DesktopWindow.setMinWindowSize(const Size(1060, 960));
    _loadCommonDependencies();
    if (!isTest) {
      print("Not Test Mode");
      _loadMacDependencies();
    } else {
      _loadTestDependencies();
    }
  }
```

I hope this provides some help.